# C# Отправка почты с Gmail опять навернулась 15:12:2020

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Есть старый добрый код для отправки мыла:

```
        public static void Send(
        string subject, 
        string message, 
        string from,
        string to,
        string password)
    {
        var mail = new MailMessage();
        var SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
        mail.To.Add(to);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = message;

        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from.Split('@')[0], password);
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Год назад или ранее он начал сбоить так как гугл ввел защиту от "плохих" программ, решилось это разрешением из юзать в
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Но вот опять...

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'Серверу SMTP требовалось защищенное
> соединение, или подлинность клиента не была установлена. Отклик
> сервера: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at'

Может кто знает как с этим безобразием справиться?

Comment: https://vc.ru/services/187142-v-rabote-servisov-google-proizoshel-massovyy-sboy-ne-rabotayut-dokumenty-gmail-youtube-i-drugie

Comment: попробуйте сменить пароль

Comment: вроде бы гугл требует в качестве username полный email, с доменом - т.к. поддерживает не-gmail домены. попробуйте убрать Split.